# What does libc_hidden_proto in the glibc standard libraries do?

Tags: c, glibc, unistd.h

I was trying to look up the prototype for the `getpgrp()` function in `unistd.h` but couldnt find it. The only line containing *getpgrp* in that file was the line `libc_hidden_proto (tcgetpgrp)` and I'm assuming this is a macro, but I dont know what it does.

I googled but couldn't find any explanations on the web for what `libc_hidden_proto` actually does. Any explanation about what the purpose of that macro is in glibc would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of glibc are you using? I don't have `libc_hidden_proto` anywhere, but I do remember it from old times ...

Comment: Thats strange. I'm using glibc 2.19 but Im also looking at the unistd.h header file in glibc 2.18, 2.20, 2.21, and 2.23 and I see libc_hidden_proto in all those versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've accidentally looked at the *internal* copy (`include/unistd.h`) instead of the public copy (`posix/unistd.h`). No, I don't understand how glibc's source is organized either.

From [include/libc-symbols.h](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/include/libc-symbols.h.html#317):

```
   The following macros are used for PLT bypassing within libc.so
   (and if needed other libraries similarly).
   First of all, you need to have the function prototyped somewhere,
   say in foo/foo.h:
   int foo (int __bar);
   If calls to foo within libc.so should always go to foo defined in libc.so,
   then in include/foo.h you add:
   libc_hidden_proto (foo)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've actually already read what it says in libc-symbols.h but I didnt understand what a PLT was and so I didnt mention libc-symbols in my question. But +1 for your answer anyways. Now I'm off to read about the PLT, GOT, ELF files, linkers, dynamic loading and the rest of the other million other things I dont know about :P

Comment: @jerry basically, it's like `-fsemantic-interposition` for just those symbols. And it only works within glibc due to all the other crazy stuff they do.